# Problems implementing jquery-anystretch for full screen background image.

Tags: jquery, background-image

I am trying to implement Jquery Anystretch into my website and have been unsuccessful in getting it to work. Jquery Anystretch will allow me to have a full image background that resizes. Below is what I have in place so far. Any help would be great. The website is http://www.jobspark.ca

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.anystretch.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> $.anystretch("/storage/fullimagebackground2.jpg", {speed: 150}); </script>
```

Here is Github link the https://github.com/danmillar/jquery-anystretch

Comment: You have incorrect path to `jquery.anystretch.min.js`. (http://www.jobspark.ca/jquery.anystretch.min.js)

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry I missed that error!

Comment: @Inferpse I just had one last question. I would like to speed up the loading of the background image. Right now it is at 150. What are the restrictions to speeding this up. I would like it to load as fast as possible. Thanks again!

Comment: Optimize your background image (save with less quality). Your image now is `1mb` size. Add loader or black background on `<body>` to make background appearence smoother. Setup cache on your server. There are many ways to speed up this.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I was able to get my background image down to 141KB and added a darker color to the background color. It seems to have made a difference. I will look into these other ways to speed things up. http://www.jobspark.ca

Answer (score 2):

I don't get why you want use javascript for a full page background, becouse browsers might have javascript turned off. There are also CSS solutions for this.

You might want to read the following article on CSS tricks on this subject, they also cover the jQuery approach.

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 1):

Rofavadeka is right, just use CSS if you're trying to make a full screen stretched background.  Just write an image tag like this:

```
<img src="..." style="position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;bottom:0px;right:0px;" />
```

As long as its put above everything else on your page (or has a lower Z index) it will appear behind everything else.